# Android dev custom dialogbox won't appear

Tags: android, dialog

Trying to create a custom dialog box. I created a new xml layout file name dialog_result:
Then on my GuessActivity, I have this code:

```
public class GuessActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guess);

}

public void checkAnswer(View view){
    EditText userinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLetter);
    String temp = userinput.getText().toString();
    char userletter = temp.charAt(0);

    Bundle fromplay = getIntent().getExtras();
    String temp2 = fromplay.getString("missing");
    char missingletter = temp2.charAt(0);

    Log.d ("temp2", temp2);

    if(userletter == missingletter){
        Log.d ("right", "right");
        resultDialogBox();
    } else {
        Log.d ("wrong", "wrong");
        resultDialogBox();
    }


}

public void resultDialogBox(){
    Dialog resultbox = new Dialog(GuessActivity.this);
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
    resultbox.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_result);

    result.setText("Correct");

    resultbox.show();
}
```

}

For the life of me, I don't know why the app is crashing. It's working until the log.d ("right", "right") and or log.d("wrong", "wrong"),; then it crashes when it calls the resultDialogBox.

the logcat:

```
04-28 10:43:33.705: D/temp2(7079): n
04-28 10:43:33.705: D/right(7079): right
04-28 10:43:33.715: D/AndroidRuntime(7079): Shutting down VM
04-28 10:43:33.715: W/dalvikvm(7079): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4161c8b0)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     ... 11 more
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at com.johnyeung.letterhunter.GuessActivity.resultDialogBox(GuessActivity.java:54)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     at com.johnyeung.letterhunter.GuessActivity.checkAnswer(GuessActivity.java:40)
04-28 10:43:33.725: E/AndroidRuntime(7079):     ... 14 more
04-28 10:43:37.899: D/libEGL(7200): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
04-28 10:43:37.899: D/libEGL(7200): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
04-28 10:43:37.899: D/libEGL(7200): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): Build Date: 12/01/13 Sun
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): Local Branch: 
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): Remote Branch: 
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): Local Patches: 
04-28 10:43:37.899: I/Adreno-EGL(7200): Reconstruct Branch: 
04-28 10:43:37.940: D/OpenGLRenderer(7200): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: could u post your crash log？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the content view on dialog. Try this.

```
public void resultDialogBox(){

Dialog resultbox = new Dialog(GuessActivity.this);
resultbox.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_result);
TextView result = (TextView)resultbox.findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
result.setText("Correct");

resultbox.show();
```

}

Comment: Make sure, you have TextView with id resulttext in layout `dialog_result`

Answer (score 0):

The error log states that your have `NullPointerException` on line 54. Did you check it?

I think the code having problem is

```
result.setText("Correct");
```

It is null because you instantiate the `result` by

```
TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
```

`findViewById` is a method called on the activity, not on the `Dialog`.  So it return `Null` if your activity does not have such `TextView`.

And you should not use the `Dialog` directly, according to the [documentation of Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).  Use `AlertDialog.Builder` instead:

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```